# VB.net express System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am trying to write a file listing custom class in VB.net 2010 express on a Win7 64 bit machine.  I installed VB.net express using an account that has administrator rights on both the machine and the network it belongs to.  I should be able to access any file on the machine and from Windows Explorer, I can.  I have been stopped cold by a “System.UnauthorizedAccessException”.

I have tried changing the manifest file.  Although that should not be needed since the account already has full permissions.  It has not worked.  Below is a fragment of the offending code.

I am beginning to wonder if it is possible read the files on a drive using managed code. I can revert to the VBA class that in capsules ancient Win32 API calls that I wrote years ago but that violates the purpose of this exercise.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub sLoadCatalog(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal intParentID As Integer)
    'Get the file list
    Dim strsearchPattern As String = "*"
    Dim fp As New FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery _
         Or FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, strPath)
    Try
        'fp.Demand()
        fp.Assert()
        Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(strPath)
        Dim FileList() As FileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles()

        If FileList.Length > 0 Then
            … Loop through the file list and do something exciting
        End If

        Dim dirFolder() As DirectoryInfo = dirInfo.GetDirectories
        If dirFolder.Length > 0 Then
            … Loop through the folder list and do something exciting 
            sLoadCatalog(strfolder, intLastID)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch e As SecurityException
        MessageBox.Show("Security Cannot access folder " & strPath)
    Catch k As UnauthorizedAccessException
        MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized Cannot access folder " & strPath)
    End Try
```

Comment: Yes you can do just about anything on your HD using Managed Code. Can you tell us what the value of `strPath` is and what your developement environment is. IE, Silverlight, WPF, Winforms, ASP? Also, what line (specifically) give you this error?

Comment: Are you *sure* that Windows Explorer allows you to access it and that you're running Windows Explorer as the same account that is running your application? I am in the administrators group on my machine, but even so, I am unable to access certain directories on my machine, and those same directories report an error when running your code. I believe this is because of Windows UAC being turned on.